# How are .page domains more secure?

Tags: security, url, https

[get.page](https://get.page) says that `.page` domains require `https`

What differences do `.page` domains provide?

Why does [ellen.page](https://ellen.page) say `Not Secure` and show an error?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing the “Not Secure” warning is because the web page or website you are visiting is not providing a secure connection. When your Chrome browser connects to a website it can either use the HTTP (insecure) or HTTPS (secure). Any page providing an HTTP connection will cause the “Not Secure” warning.

Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure is an extension of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol. It is used for secure communication over a computer network, and is widely used on the Internet. In HTTPS, the communication protocol is encrypted using Transport Layer Security or, formerly, Secure Sockets Layer.

The Hypertext Transfer Protocol is an Session layer protocol for distributed, collaborative, hypermedia information systems.

HTTPS is HTTP with encryption. The only difference between the two protocols is that HTTPS uses TLS (SSL) to encrypt normal HTTP requests and responses. As a result, HTTPS is far more secure than HTTP. A website that uses HTTP has `http://` in its URL, while a website that uses HTTPS has `https://`.

`.page` domains are different because they require HTTPS certificates.

ellen.page normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to ellen.page this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be ellen.page, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.